# Why cannot create multiple web socket connections to same host?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

The answer to this question suggests [Multiple Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498429/multiple-websockets)

> can only create one WebSocket connection from a client
>   to a specific port on the host.

But in the same way that multiple REST services are exposed to access different services why cannot create multiple web socket connections ?

So for example :

```
Rest service1 accesses current count of food items
Rest service2 accesses current count of drink items
```

This doesn't appear to transform to (as just one connection is allowed per client) :

```
Socket service1 accesses current count of food items
Socket service2 accesses current count of drink items
```

Comment: It _suggests_ that, but it gets debunked in the comments.

Comment: Someone should post an answer there that makes the debunking more definitive as it's not at all clear at a first reading that the one answer there is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How WebSocket server handles multiple incoming connection requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516962/how-websocket-server-handles-multiple-incoming-connection-requests)