# Getting more than one connection from dbcp

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to get more than one connection from ***Tomcat***'s `dbcp` asynchronously? I mean, the same client has access more than one db-connection instance?

Comment: Please read the 'stateful protocol' answer here:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329641/how-do-multiple-clients-connect-simultaneously-to-one-port-say-80-on-a-server

Comment: @Grif-fin Don't see how it answers my question. It has nothing to do woth tomcat ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Tomcat uses HTTP protocol which is TCP based. TCP is stateful protocol (please refer to the link I gave in the comment).

If you connect multiple times to your webserver from the same client it will open different ports for each connection which means the direct answer to your question is *yes*, same client can make multiple connections to a webserver.

Comment: I still don't see how it relates to getting multiple db-connections from the pool for the same client.

Comment: Same with DB connections they are TCP based so you can make multiple connections to a DB from the same client.