# Can a TcpClient be connected to 2 different ports?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

My software need to listen to 2 different ports at the same time, I need something like that :

```
Client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);
Client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8002);
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make two `TcpClient`s?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this isn't possible with the same client object, but of those you can have as many as you need, as suggested by Glorin Oakenfoot.

Comment: Also, if you are *listening*, as in listening for connections, you should probably have a look at the `TcpListener` class.

Comment: ... and if you want to listen on two separate ports, create two listeners...

Comment: Just use two separate TcpClients. It makes no sense to want to use the same one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a 1 connection, TCP Clients are connected individually so you need to make 2 port connection for multiple connectivity. For example, in Terminal you can't have multiple connection until you open a new window for second connection.

See [Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329672/2556515) answer on here, give you some clear view, but there is more to it.

#### Brief explanation:

For a stateful protocol (like TCP), a connection is identified by a 4-tuple consisting of source and destination ports and source and destination IP addresses. So, if two different machines connect to the same port on a third machine, there are two distinct connections because the source IPs differ. If the same machine (or two behind NAT or otherwise sharing the same IP address) connects twice to a single remote end, the connections are differentiated by source port (which is generally a random high-numbered port).

Comment: My software have two servers listening two devices, one server in TCP, the other in UDP mode. The UI application is listening to that two servers and displays the informations. I added another TcpClients and that seems to work.