# How send typed message back from server side to more than one clients simultaneously

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I have list of socket whic is connected to my 'server program'.if One of  clients write something  I want to  send this message to all clients simutaneously but code below not working simutaneously  how can I do this in python

```
for i in range(len(Connection_list)):
    tempsoc=soc
    if Connection_list[i]==soc:
        reply = "me-->" + message+"\n"
        tempsoc=soc
    else :
        reply = "Message from "+ str(addr[0])+ ":"+ str(addr[1])+"-->" + message +"\n"
        tempsoc=Connection_list[i]
    tempsoc.send(reply.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do multiple clients connect simultaneously to one port, say 80, on a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329641/how-do-multiple-clients-connect-simultaneously-to-one-port-say-80-on-a-server)

Comment: This code is not a duplicate of the one labelled (which only tries to explain generic client/server interaction), but it is a bad question that I'm voting to close.  @serder, please give a lot more detail: what is `soc`?  In what way is it not working?  Is it sending any messages?  Giving any errors?

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein firstly soc is created socket by server when conncetion happen from  client , sending message from server to clients whic are in Connection_list not working only current socket working not other connections in list. I am basicaly making simple chat program when one user typing something and hit enter other users must see the message.

Comment: None of this helps us debug. Please ask a question with a  [mcve].